# Use of volatile in Singleton(Bill Pughs Solution)

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, volatile

Given below is a java class using Bill Pugh singleton solution.

```
public class Singleton {

    int nonVolatileVariable;

    private static class SingletonHelper {
        private static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
    }

    public int getNonVolatileVariable() {
        return nonVolatileVariable;
    }

    public void setNonVolatileVariable(int nonVolatileVariable) {
        this.nonVolatileVariable= nonVolatileVariable;
    }
}
```

I have read in many places that this approach is thread safe. So if I understand it correctly, then the singleton instance is created only once and all threads accessing the `getInstance` method will receive the same instance of the class `Singleton`. However I was wondering if the threads can locally cache the obtained singleton object. Can they? If yes then doesn't that would mean that each thread can change the instance field `nonVolatileVariable` to different values which might create problems.

I know that there are other singleton creation methods such as enum singleton, but I am particularly interested in this singleton creation method.

So my question is that, is there a need to use the volatile keyword like 
`int volatile nonVolatileVariable;` to make sure that the singleton using this approach is truely thread safe? Or is it already truly thread safe? If so how?

Comment: Without `volatile` it may happen that some thread does not see changes to `nonVolatileVariable` made by another thread.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is that, is there a need to use the volatile keyword
>   like  int volatile nonVolatileVariable; to make sure that the
>   singleton using this approach is truly thread safe? Or is it already
>   truly thread safe? If so how?

The singleton pattern ensures that a single instance of the class is created. It doesn't ensures that fields and methods be thread-safe and volatile doesn't ensure it either.

> However I was wondering if the threads can locally cache the obtained
>   singleton object ?

According to the memory model in Java, yes they can.

> if yes then doesn't that would mean that each thread can change the
>   instance field nonVolatileVariable to different values which might
>   create problems.

Indeed but you would still a problem of consistency with a `volatile` variable because `volatile` handles the memory visibility question but it doesn't handle the synchronization between threads.

Try the following code where multiple threads increment a volatile `int` `100` times.
You will see that you could not get `100` at each time as result.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Singleton {

    volatile int  volatileInt;

    private static class SingletonHelper {
        private static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
    }

    public int getVolatileInt() {
        return volatileInt;
    }

    public void setVolatileInt(int volatileInt ) {
        this.volatileInt = volatileInt ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        List<Callable<Void>> callables = IntStream.range(0, 100)
                                                  .mapToObj(i -> {
                                                      Callable<Void> callable = () -> {
                                                          Singleton.getInstance().setVolatileInt(Singleton.getInstance().getVolatileInt()+1);
                                                          return null;
                                                      };
                                                      return callable;
                                                  })
                                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

        executorService.invokeAll(callables);

        System.out.println(Singleton.getInstance().getVolatileInt());
    }

}
```

To ensure that each thread takes into consideration other invocations, you have to use external synchronization and in this case make the variable volatile is not required.

For example :

```
synchronized (Singleton.getInstance()) {
  Singleton.getInstance()
           .setVolatileInt(Singleton.getInstance().getVolatileInt() + 1);
}
```

And in this case, volatile is not required any longer.

Comment: Interesting. So does that mean that there is noway we can ensure that my Singleton class can be made strictly thread safe just by adding volatile or synchronized within?

Comment: The external synchronization I refered to the end of my answer is java thread synchronization. I added an example.

Comment: What I understood from the example is that, we have to use external synchronization in the places where we call the getInstance() or setter method.But that is like putting additional responsibility on the caller right. Can we somehow make our singleton instance thread safe such that the getInstance() method simply returns a thread safe object??

Comment: Methods of an object are thread safe in the limit of the methods concurrently  invoked on. For example `Vector` is thread safe but performing a composed processing : invoking methods `get()` and `add()`  without synchronization doesn't  guarantee that the composed  processing by thread safe because **you have a race condition**.Of course if you invoke `getVolatileInt()` and `setVolatileInt()` independently  of the result of each other, you would not have race condition any longer and external synchronization is not required.

Answer (score 1):

The specific guarantee of this type of singleton basically works like this:

1. Each class has a unique lock for class initialization.
2. Any action which could cause class initialization (such as accessing a static method) is required to first acquire this lock, check if the class needs to be initialized and, if so, initialize it.
3. If the JVM can determine that the class is already initialized and the current thread can see the effect of that, then it can skip step 2, including skipping acquiring the lock.

(This is documented in [§12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2).)

In other words, what's guaranteed here is that all threads must at least see the effects of the assignment in `private static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();`, and anything else that was performed during static initialization of the `SingletonHelper` class.

Your analysis that concurrent reads and writes of the non-`volatile` variable can be inconsistent between threads is correct, although the language specification isn't written in terms of caching. The way the language specification is written is that reads and writes can appear out of order. For example, suppose the following sequence of events, listed chronologically:

```
nonVolatileVariable is 0
ThreadA sets nonVolatileVariable to 1
ThreadB reads nonVolatileVariable (what value should it see?)
```

The language specification allows `ThreadB` to see the value 0 when it reads `nonVolatileVariable`, which is as if the events had happened in the following order:

```
nonVolatileVariable is 0
ThreadB reads nonVolatileVariable (and sees 0)
ThreadA sets nonVolatileVariable to 1
```

In practice, this is due to caching, but the language specification doesn't say what may or may not be cached (except [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5), as a brief mention), it only specifies the order of events.

---

One extra note regarding thread-safety: some actions are always considered atomic, such as reads and writes of object references ([§17.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7)), so there are *some* cases where the use of a non-`volatile` variable can be considered thread-safe, but it depends on what you're specifically doing with it. There can still be memory inconsistency but concurrent reads and writes can't somehow *interleave*, so you can't end up with e.g. an invalid pointer value somehow. It's therefore sometimes safe to use non-`volatile` variables for e.g. lazily-initialized fields *if it doesn't matter that the initialization procedure could happen more than once*. I know of at least one place in the JDK where this is used, in [`java.lang.reflect.Field`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/reflect/Field.java#Field) (also see [this comment in the file](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/reflect/Field.java#1072)), but it's not the norm.